# Как заменить все экранирующие символы \\ в файле

Tags: python

Есть файл на подобии

```
\\112233\\445566\\778899
\\223344\\556677\\889911
```

При чтении файла побайтово вывод следующий

```
['\\\\112233\\\\445566\\\\778899\n', '\\\\223344\\\\556677\\\\889911\n']
```

Вопрос как заменить символы в файле что-бы при открытии через редактор был

```
\112233\445566\778899
\223344\556677\889911
```

А при чтении побайтово был

```
['\\112233\\445566\\778899\n', '\\223344\\556677\\889911\n']
```

Comment: *>что-бы при открытии через редактор был* - так и заменить.

Comment: регулярные выражения тебе в помощь

Answer (score 1):

Просто экранируйте обратный слеш

`\` в представлении компьютера (вывод и обработка) - `\\`, слеш, который находится на первом месте экранирует второй слеш.

`\\\\` - так наш префикс видит компьютер, в нашем же представлении это просто два обратных слеша. Чтобы соответственно заменить 2 слеша на 1, мы просто применяем строковый метод `.replace('\\\\', '\\')` к исходному тексту.

Пример кода:

```
with open("yourFile.txt", mode="r") as f:
  data = f.read()
  data = data.replace("\\\\", "\\")

with open("yourFile.txt", mode="w") as f:
  f.write(data)
```